# Regex to find text inside inverted commas C#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a command line tool to upgrade a webapi 1.0 project to webapi 2.0.

And I want to read the referenced version numbers in packages.config file inside the project.

My problem is how do I find the version number and replace it with appropriate version number. And this string to find can be any random version number and I don't want to hardcode this and extract. I am looking for an efficient way to extract the following string with preceding and succeeding space.

```
 version="a.b.c.d"
```

I am completely clueless on how I would find this and replace the `a.b.c.d` to `x.y.z`

Sample line in config file:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: Looks like an xml parser would make things easier for you.

Comment: You should be careful about requiring the attribute the be surrounded by space characters. `<package version="a.b.c.d"/>` is also valid Xml.

Comment: Ok, let me see what I can do with XmlParser.
Because I don't want to complicate things. I am using a `File.ReadAllLines` and then matching the line I want with a keyword, then making changes to it. And then saving this new line back to its original line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this: `\s+version=".+?"\s+` would match the text `version=` and any contents within the quotation marks. So you could do something like this: Find what: `\s+version=".+?"\s+` replace with: `version="x.y.z"`.

The above however will replace all the `version=` strings, which I do not know if it is something which you are after.

Comment: How would I put the pattern in a string?

Would this suffice ?

`string pattern = "\s+version=".+?"\s+";`

Above line gives me an error called `bad compile constant value`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that RegEx is here the best approach.
.NET offers a [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which are the best solution here IMO.